# Laravel Guzzle Client Server synchronisation

Tags: php, laravel, http, synchronization, guzzle

So I'm new to the web world and i'm working on some project where i'm using Laravel 5.6,

to wrap it all a Client fill a form and submit it, the Web Application take that POST request, do some treating on the informations and Send them to another complete different Server (running a backend web app too,let's name it X) through a POST HTTP request, for that i'm using the latest version of GuzzleHttp and it's working just fine !

Now here's my problem, i need to make the Client wait until the Web application get a response from X with some custom data (not just a '200') and then echo it to the Client !

Client(Send and wait) -> WebApp -> X -> WebApp -> Client

As i said, sending from the WebAPP to X using GuzzleHttp is working fine and i'm getting a 200 response, but how do i make it wait for custom data to echo it to the client, and how do i send it from X to that specific session of the client !

I searched for this but didn't find much of a thing !

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
$client=new Client();
$response=client->request('POST','http://192.168.1.49/register',
                                   ['form_params' => 
                                        [
                                           'foo' => 'bar'
                                        ]
                                   ]);
dd($response);
```

When i do this it works just fine , i receive a "200" response, but then again that's not my problem ! 
I appreciate the feedback, kind of lost !

Comment: So you're saying that the response returns 200, but there's another response that you're waiting for *after* the fact?

Comment: Pretty much yeah, i'm not really interested in 200, if had to make it more clear, i wish if the $response contains some custom data that i would be sending from the other webapp X in response to the initiated POST request from the original (first) webapp !

Comment: That's because you're just dumping the `$response`. What you want is `$response->getBody()`

Comment: yes i get it, but how do i implement it from the Webapp X side ? i mean how do i send informations to the same session, so that i can echo it to the Client !?